# Some Problems while learning STL

Tags: c++, stl

I am using g++ in CodeBlocks IDE in Ubuntu.
I am new to STL and some part of C++.

Q1: //answered

```
std::istream_iterator< std::string > begin ( dictionaryFile );
std::istream_iterator< std::string > end;
std::vector< std::string> dictionary;
std::copy ( begin, end, std::back_inserter ( dictionary ) );
```

is correct, but when I changed

```
std::istream_iterator< std::string > end;
```

into

```
std::istream_iterator< std::string > end();
```

the compiler says no matching function call at the fourth line.

Q2: //sorry i did not make the problem clear the first time

```
struct PS : std::pair< std::string, std::string > {
PS();
static struct FirstLess: std::binary_function< PS, PS, bool> {
    bool operator() ( const PS & p, const PS & q ) const {
        return p.first < q.first;
    }
} firstLess1; };


struct FirstLess: std::binary_function< PS, PS, bool> {
bool operator() ( const PS & p, const PS & q ) const {
    return p.first < q.first;
}} firstLess2;
```

Note that the only difference between firstLess1 and firstLess2 is that firstLess1 is declared in PS.

when I call the function :

```
k = std::find_if ( j + 1, finis, std::not1 ( std::bind1st ( PS::firstLess1, *j ) ) );
```

the compiler gave me an error 'undefined reference to PS::firstLess1'.
and then I changed to

```
k = std::find_if ( j + 1, finis, std::not1 ( std::bind1st ( firstLess2, *j ) ) );
```

then it passed the compile.

More strange, in some other part of the program, i used both

```
j = std::adjacent_find ( j , finis, PS::firstLess1 );
j = std::adjacent_find ( j , finis, firstLess2 );
```

and the compiler did not gave me an error.

Comment: OK. I've figured out how to solve the second question.(but still don't know why)
just use k = std::find_if ( j + 1, finis, std::not1 ( std::bind1st ( PS::FirstLess(), *j ) ) ); is OK
or you can add const PS::FirstEqual PS::firstEqual1 = PS::FirstEqual(); after the declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::istream_iterator< std::string > end();` C++ interpretes this as declaration of function which name is `end` return value type is `std::istream_iterator< std::string >` and argument list is empty. Thats why you get such error. In C++ to make any object by calling default constructor of its class you just must do this `type_name variable_name;`. `type_name variable_name();` will be interpreted as function declaration.

Comment: This is what we call [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Answer (score 2):

A1: already answered sufficiently 
A2: <s>add a const to the declaration of firstLess, OR</s> define the firstLess object in a cpp file (see [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr038.htm))

Comment: +1 for *define the firstLess object*, namely in the enclosing scope (see the top line in the linked page).  In this case adding `const` makes no difference as that only works for static members of integral type, not structs.  (What is surprising is that the compiler allows the `adjacent_find()` call.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: fixed it. But should it really only wrok for integral types ? it has worked for me with POD structs aswell in the past...

Comment: I don't know :)  I can only say that it should not be expected to work.  But a compiler is free to allow anything that doesn't contradict the standard, and I don't think this does.

Answer (score 1):

A1:

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized.
>
> [ Note: since () is not permitted by the syntax for initializer,
>
> X a ();
>
> is not the declaration of an object of class X, but the declaration of a function taking no argument and returning an X.
>
> The form () is permitted in certain other initialization contexts (5.3.4, 5.2.3, 12.6.2). — end note ]

A2:

I'm not really sure what you want, std::find_if and std::adjacent_find do something comepletely different. But anyway, here is some working code inspired by yours.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> TwoStrings;

struct FirstLess : std::binary_function<TwoStrings, TwoStrings, bool>
{
    bool operator() (const TwoStrings& p, const TwoStrings& q) const {
        return p.first < q.first;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<TwoStrings> v;
    std::vector<TwoStrings>::iterator it;
    v.push_back(TwoStrings("4. Here's ", "Johnny"));
    v.push_back(TwoStrings("1. Here's ", "Johnny"));
    v.push_back(TwoStrings("2. Here's ", "Johnny"));
    v.push_back(TwoStrings("2. Here's ", "Johnny"));
    v.push_back(TwoStrings("3. Here's ", "Johnny"));

    it = std::adjacent_find(v.begin(), v.end(), FirstLess());
    std::cout << it->first << it->second << std::endl;

    it = std::find_if(v.begin() , v.end(), std::not1(std::bind1st(FirstLess(), *(v.begin()))));
    std::cout << it->first << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

A the output is:

```
1. Here's Johnny
4. Here's Johnny
```