# C++ - What is this doing if the constructor is private?

Tags: c++, constructor, private, most-vexing-parse

In the code below, why does the compiler not complain for mClass2?

```
class CMyClass{
private:
    CMyClass(){}
};

void TestMethod(){
    CMyClass mClass1;   //Fails.
    CMyClass mClass2(); //Works.
}
```

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296090/some-problems-while-learning-stl/4296118#4296118

Comment: Also known as: Most Vexing Parse (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you've just declared a function `mClass2` of zero arguments that returns a `CMyClass`. That's a valid option since there could be, say, a `static CMyClass` instance which that function has access to. Note that `CMyClass` still has a public copy constructor.

(To convince yourself, compile this module to assembler and observe that commenting out the line `CMyClass mClass2();` produces the same output.)

Comment: Also, a valid move constructor.

Answer (score 10):

Because it is declaring a function and not calling the constructor as you think.

This is called as the **[Most Vexing Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)** in c++.

```
CMyClass mClass2();
```

declares a function `mClass2()` which takes no parameter and returns `CMyClass`

Comment: **Most vexing parse** - can't say I've ever heard of that before, I'll have a look at that, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

The second one is a function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

People ought to move to the uniform syntax initialization in C++0x/C++11 using the {} brackets instead which removes this issue.

Class C{};

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#uniform-init